# Ant build prompt when moving Java files?

Tags: java

I'm trying to zip my Java file for submission which I'm able to do but when I unzip it and open my file, running it causes a window to pop up asking to choose and "Ant Build" which returns an error. I zipped and unzipped the entire project with the package and class, and the code opens, it just wont run.

Edit: This is in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse there is a specific way to send/get your project to/from a .zip. The process is called importing and exporting. Both these options can be found when you right click on your project in the **Package Explorer**. The problem you're experiencing can be fixed by properly importing the project into eclipse which I'll explain:

Importing:

1. If you have the .zip file, locate your **Java Workspace** (in explorer) where all your previous java project are stored.
2. Once found, extract the contents of the .zip file to your **Workspace** (the .zip should contain the project (as a regular folder) then all other files/folder within the like bin and src).
3. Once the .zip has been extracted, open eclipse and in the **Package Explorer** panel right click, this will open a list of options. Select **Import**.
4. This will open a new window. From here select **General** -> **Existing Project into Workspace** then click **Next** (at the bottom of the window).
5. To select the root directory click **Browse** (navigate to your recently extracted project (in your workspace)) and select it.
6. Then ensure in the **Projects** panel you've clicked the check box. Once you've done this click **Finish** and your project will be properly uploaded into your workspace. From here you'll be able to run it.

Note: For the first build you may have to navigate to your main class in the project, right click and select **Run As -> Java Application**.

Exporting:

1. First navigate to it in the project explorer (while you're using
   eclipse)
2. Then ensure that you project is open (you can view the files inside) and right click on it. Now you'll see a large list of options, selected **Export**.
3. Once the export window is open, select **General** -> **Archive File** then hit **Next** (at the bottom).
4. Ensure all the files you want are selected (right panel) as well as your project itself (left panel), then select the destination you'd like to send the project to (where to save it as a .zip)
5. Hit **Finish** and the process is over. You can now locate to the destination you saved it and you'll have a .zip of your entire project.